# Proving a point lies on a line given a vector equation

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let L be a line in $\Bbb{R^2}$ with vector equation $\vec{a}=b\vec{c}$ how would you prove that a point $(p_1,p_2)$ lies on L if and only if $p_1c_2=p_2c_1$ where $c_1,c_2$ are the respective components of $\vec{c}$

I can do the forward proof, but the backwards proof is giving me trouble. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $p_1c_2=p_2c_1$.  Then note that $(p_1, p_2)$ is on the line $a=bc$ iff $p_1 = bc_1$ and $p_2 = bc_2$ for some $b\in \Bbb R$.

Now we know that $a=bc$ defines a line iff $c\ne 0$, so at least one of $c_1$ and $c_2$ must be nonzero.  WLOG, let's assume $c_2 \ne 0$.  Then we see that
$$p_1 = \frac{p_2}{c_2}c_1$$
But it's also clear that 
$$p_2 = \frac{p_2}{c_2}c_2$$
Thus $(p_1, p_2) = b(c_1, c_2)$ where $b=\dfrac{p_2}{c_2}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Plug your point into the equation for $\vec{a}$. Can you determine what $b$ must be?